# how to force a machine to go through proxy when it as an exception not to go

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy, squid

I'm in a private domain where the client machines need a proxy server to access the internet. 
All the machines have an exception where every request to servers in my domain don't need to go through the proxy:
don't use proxy to:
.mydomain.com, 171.11.0.0/16 and so on...

Well, I now have a machine with an external IP, but I want my clients to access the machine using the dns name: www.mydomain.com.

However, since they need a proxy to go to the internet, but the browser has an exception not to go through proxy when using the domain, they never reach the machine and the connection times out.

My DNS server (bind) has the www machine with the external IP.
If I use directly the IP address, it goes to a "under construction" page, because the server outside is configured with a named virtual server and I don't have access to it.

How can I solve this problem? how can I force the machines to go through the proxy even if they are configured not to go ?

if i remove the exception, all the other requests to servers inside will not work...

Cheers

Bruno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very confused as to what is currently happening and what you mean by "an exception"

However an obvious way to address the problem is to use a proxy [auto-config script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) on the browsers:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
   if (dnsDomainIs(host, ".mydomain.com"))
         return "DIRECT";
   else 
         return "PROXY yourproxy.mydomain.com:3129";
}
```

(for preference you would serve this up from an internal webserver or put it on a shared drive so you can easily deploy updates).

Comment: I have a proxy.pac (or wpad.dat) where are all the exceptions for not using the proxy. by an exception i mean all the address where is not needed for the browser to use the proxy server...(which are all the internal servers). The proxy is only needed to access the internet... (in this case, it's my domain, but with an external - internet - ip address). the client computers are configured to use the proxy server to access internet addresses and not use it when the fqdn is an internal domain name. In this case, it's an internet address with an internal domain name..

Comment: I've used your sugestion, and added an entry in my proxy in my proxy.pac:  if (isInNet(host,"111.111.111.111","255.255.255.255")) { return "PROXY proxy.domain.com:8080";}